# Android "speak" with a service

Tags: android, service, connection

I have an android class that extends a `service`. I can start the service with `startService(intent)` and stop it with `stopService(intent)`.

But what if I need send some information to the service after I've started it?

In my case for example I need to call some methods. How can I do it?

I thought is a simple thing but I looked for it on the web without find an easy way. Do I need to use a remote service or there is something easier?

Thank in advance

Comment: Have you tried binding your service as in the example on the official documentation : [Local Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample)

Comment: you can create a remote service and call its methods using aidl/ipc its the best option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or just use `startService()` and send an `Intent` with some data along. No need to be complex.

Comment: PS: better start accepting answers, I'm seeing none of your questions accepted as answered yet. People will start ignoring your questions soon

Answer (score 0):

Use [Broadcasts and Broadcast Receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Answer (score 0):

To call methods in the Service from an Activity you need to bind the Service in an Activity. Check out [Bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) from the official developers guide.

If you don't want to use an Activity then resort to Nieks suggestion with Broadcasts and Broadcast Receivers.

But then again if you need to call methods in you service on a regular basis, maybe it shouldn't be a service.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your service over to an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and it will handel the service life cycle for you.

Each startService(intent) will represent a new "job" for the service.

If you need notification of progress or completion Use [Broadcasts and Broadcast Receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).